# Ошибка Yii2 при установке ReCaptcha на готовый сайт

Tags: php, yii2, recaptcha

Пытаюсь установить ReCaptcha на готовый сайт на yii2 используя https://github.com/himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget и https://yiico.ru/blog/496-yii2-recaptcha-widget (без composer)

Получаю ошибку при открытии сайта:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class
> "app\models\ReCaptchaValidator" does not exist in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:507 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(507): ReflectionClass->__construct('app\models\ReCa...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(385):
> yii\di\Container->getDependencies('app\models\ReCa...') #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(170):
> yii\di\Container->build('app\models\ReCa...', Array, Array) #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(365):
> yii\di\Container->get('app\models\ReCa...', Array, Array) #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\validators\Validator.php(230):
> yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array) #5
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(461):
> yii\validators\Validator::createValidator('app\models\ReCa...',
> Object(app\models\CustomersForm), Array, Array) #6
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(413):
> yii\base\Model->createValidators() #7
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(188):
> yii\base\Model->getValidators() #8
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(808):
> yii\base\Model->scenarios() #9
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(427):
> yii\base\Model->activeAttributes() #10
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(487):
> yii\base\Model->getActiveValidators('theme') #11
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(932):
> yii\base\Model->isAttributeRequired('theme') #12
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(652):
> yii\widgets\ActiveField->addAriaAttributes(Array) #13
> C:\xampp\htdocs\views\site\customers.php(66):
> yii\widgets\ActiveField->dropDownList(Array, Array) #14
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(347):
> require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #15
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(257):
> yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\xampp\htdocs...', Array) #16
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(156):
> yii\base\View->renderFile('C:\xampp\htdocs...', Array,
> Object(app\controllers\SiteController)) #17
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(407):
> yii\base\View->render('customers', Array,
> Object(app\controllers\SiteController)) #18
> C:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\SiteController.php(181):
> yii\base\Controller->render('customers', Array) #19 [internal
> function]: app\controllers\SiteController->actionCustomers(NULL) #20
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #21
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(178):
> yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array) #22
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(552):
> yii\base\Controller->runAction('customers', Array) #23
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103):
> yii\base\Module->runAction('site/customers', Array) #24
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(384):
> yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request)) #25
> C:\xampp\htdocs\web\index.php(14): yii\base\Application->run() #26
> {main} Next yii\di\NotInstantiableException: Failed to instantiate
> component or class "app\models\ReCaptchaValidator". in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:509 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(385): yii\di\Container->getDependencies('app\models\ReCa...') #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(170):
> yii\di\Container->build('app\models\ReCa...', Array, Array) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(365):
> yii\di\Container->get('app\models\ReCa...', Array, Array) #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\validators\Validator.php(230):
> yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array) #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(461):
> yii\validators\Validator::createValidator('app\models\ReCa...',
> Object(app\models\CustomersForm), Array, Array) #5
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(413):
> yii\base\Model->createValidators() #6
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(188):
> yii\base\Model->getValidators() #7
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(808):
> yii\base\Model->scenarios() #8
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(427):
> yii\base\Model->activeAttributes() #9
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Model.php(487):
> yii\base\Model->getActiveValidators('theme') #10
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(932):
> yii\base\Model->isAttributeRequired('theme') #11
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(652):
> yii\widgets\ActiveField->addAriaAttributes(Array) #12
> C:\xampp\htdocs\views\site\customers.php(66):
> yii\widgets\ActiveField->dropDownList(Array, Array) #13
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(347):
> require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #14
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(257):
> yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\xampp\htdocs...', Array) #15
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(156):
> yii\base\View->renderFile('C:\xampp\htdocs...', Array,
> Object(app\controllers\SiteController)) #16
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(407):
> yii\base\View->render('customers', Array,
> Object(app\controllers\SiteController)) #17
> C:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\SiteController.php(181):
> yii\base\Controller->render('customers', Array) #18 [internal
> function]: app\controllers\SiteController->actionCustomers(NULL) #19
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #20
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(178):
> yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array) #21
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(552):
> yii\base\Controller->runAction('customers', Array) #22
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103):
> yii\base\Module->runAction('site/customers', Array) #23
> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(384):
> yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request)) #24
> C:\xampp\htdocs\web\index.php(14): yii\base\Application->run() #25
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php
> on line 509

Ошибка появляется после добавления в форму:

```
public $reCaptcha;

public function rules()
{
  return [
      // ...
      [['reCaptcha'], \himiklab\yii2\recaptcha\ReCaptchaValidator2::className(),
        'secret' => 'your secret key', // unnecessary if reСaptcha is already configured
        'uncheckedMessage' => 'Please confirm that you are not a bot.'],
  ];
}
```

Строки 499-515 из C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php

```
protected function getDependencies($class)
    {
        if (isset($this->_reflections[$class])) {
            return [$this->_reflections[$class], $this->_dependencies[$class]];
        }

        $dependencies = [];
        try {
            $reflection = new ReflectionClass($class);
        } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
            throw new NotInstantiableException(
                $class,
                'Failed to instantiate component or class "' . $class . '".',
                0,
                $e
            );
        }
```

Comment: В чем сакральный смысл устанавливать расширения без Composer? Это очень плохая практика.